# Как можно переопределить метод в методе?

Tags: php

Друзья, приветствую!
Озадачен вопросом...

Есть родительский класс с методом и есть дочерний класс:

```
class Base {
  public function action() {
    return "example 1";
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  public function actionOne() {
    что-то происходит...
  }
}
```

Как изменить `return "example 1"` в методе `action`, к примеру, на `"example 2"` при обращении к методу `actionOne`?

А если более конкретно, то, например, при загрузке страницы в `layout`, вызывается `$this->getCannonicalUrl`, но при странице с пагинацией чтобы не добавлялся `/2/` и т. д.

Comment: вероятно [так](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f81531d3fc2b970f50b4f66832508b9eb809147b) ?

Comment: Спасибо. Уже решил, именно таким решением... Но почему именно свойство protected ?

Comment: свойство protected для того, что бы нельзя было его изменить за пределами классов.